# angular UI route not work on page reload or direct URL hit

Tags: html, angularjs, angular-ui-router, virtualhost

when i click on ui-sref="state1" or ui-sref="state" it's working fine, change the url like as http://demo/state1 or http://demo/state2 but on direct hit the url it's not working [image]

HTML CODE

```
<html>
<base href="/">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.2/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-router/0.4.2/angular-ui-router.min.js"></script>
<body>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="personCtrl">


    <div ui-view></div>
    <!-- We'll also add some navigation: -->
    <a ui-sref="state1">State 1</a>
    <a ui-sref="state2">State 2</a>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

JS code

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ui.router']);
app.controller('personCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.firstName = "John";
    $scope.lastName = "Doe";
    $scope.fullName = function() {
        return $scope.firstName + " " + $scope.lastName;
    };
});
app.config(function($stateProvider,$locationProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
  // 
  // For any unmatched url, redirect to /state1 
  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/state1");
  // 
  // Now set up the states 
  $stateProvider
    .state('state1', {
      url: "/state1",
      template: "<div>state1</div>"
    })

    .state('state2', {
      url: "/state2",
      template: "<div>state2</div>"
    })
    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
});
```

Comment: your server has to be set up to support `html5Mode`.  see https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Frequently-Asked-Questions#how-to-configure-your-server-to-work-with-html5modehttps://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Frequently-Asked-Questions#how-to-configure-your-server-to-work-with-html5mode

Comment: whats your root url ? does demo works?

Comment: URL changes in the ng1 router aren't a real URL change in the server only local to the client. The ng1 router just stitches together templates and data locally detached from what goes on the server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to write url rewrite rules for your server to redirect to index.html for any request.

[Look here for details](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/$location#relative-links)